# TCP IP Listener Android

Tags: android, tcp, ip, broadcastreceiver, listener

Here is the idea behind what I am trying to accomplish, I am currently communicating with Bluetooth sensors and sending the data at periodic intervals to a remote server over Wi-Fi, now in between transmissions I put the system in sleep mode to save power.

However, I want my processing thread to be interrupted from it's sleep upon reception of a packet from the server. I know I can do this simply by creating another thread in an infinite work loop and waking it up to check for incoming data from the socket upon time intervals, but I was wondering whether there was a nicer way of accomplishing this, e.g. registering a listener, starting a background service to check for reception, creating a custom broadcast receiver ... etc.

I have tried searching online with no success, I don't want the code to do this, but maybe a few links to point me in the right direction so that I can do it myself.
Thanks

Comment: Here are a few links I found useful (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607351/periodically-fetching-data-polling-from-the-server-in-android) and also (http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2010/08/23/android-tutorial-reducing-power-consumption-of-connected-apps/) I decided to use the alarm manager which triggers an intent and on Receive I inquire for the number of bytes available, if >0 wake up and service incoming request. I would be glad to hear other more power efficient implementations