# Establishing a persistent connection in Android

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, connection

For one of the screens in my android application, I need to listen to server indeterminately - ie; I have few fields in the screen whose values change continuously so long the screen is kept open. The values to be updated will be provided by the server continuously. I understand that normal http connection would not be a solution here. Also, I do not wish to make continuous http requests owing to performance reasons. What is the best way out in order to accomplish this.Is GCM Cloud Connection Server a good solution for my requirement. Or are there better solutions? Please advise.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a two options.  If you don't own the server yourself I would start a service to run in the background and bind to it.  The service would poll the server at some time interval depending upon how often you want the values to update.  The activity would then receive periodic updates and update the views.  Given that the information that you're updating is really not all that large, updates every 30s to a minute wouldn't take a toll on performance at all since all of the work would be done in an asynchronous task.

[Using an AlarmManager to accomplish this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607351/periodically-fetching-data-polling-from-the-server-in-android)

If you own the server then you could implement the GCM model, and only send updates when data changes.  This is assuming that every user of the app would get the same set of updates of course.

[Introduction to GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping screen on could be battery consuming. If you own the server the changes can be pushed to the app using the GCM service.
As far as I understand, GCM bundles push messages from several server trying to push the messages together and hence is an optimised way to communicate.

Alternatively, you can bring up a server which can keep polling the original server and push the changes to the app through GCM.